# Using BiIntPredicate in Java

Tags: java, predicate

I have the following interface

```
public interface BiIntPredicate
{
   public boolean test(int x, int y);    
}
```

and have this class

```
public class Class
{
   public static final int BOUND=5;

   public static void printFigure(BiIntPredicate b) {
       for (int i=1; i<=BOUND; i++) {
           for (int j=1; j<=BOUND; j++) {
               if (b.test(i,j)) System.out.print("*");
               else System.out.print(" ");
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
   }
}
```

I am using blueJ and am trying to figure out the parameters to enter in order to print out this figure.

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

I don't understand how to enter the parameters to print this out.

Answer (score 1):

To print asterisks unconditionally, call it like this:

```
printFigure((i, j) -> true);
```

Comment: that worked thanks! is there a way to call it with an integer instead of true?

Comment: @aqw91 I'm not sure what you mean. `test()` returns a `boolean`; your lambda must do the same.

Comment: oh yeah sorry! so if i were to want to print the stars with different dimensions i would need a different method?

Comment: The dimensions come from `BOUND`, which isn't defined in your method or lambda.